# How can i use connection strings from class lib's App.config?

Tags: c#, dll, app-config

I have a class library and my other projects are using it. And also i have some connection strings. i want to use them from just class lib's App.config file. But when i use ConfigurationManager in my class lib for reading connection strings, program looks my current project's App.config or Web.config files.

How can i use connection strings from class lib's App.config file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [.Net app.config in library project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742929/net-app-config-in-library-project)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a Xml file in your class library. You should read your connection strings from it.

Answer (score 0):

Copy them from the class lib's config file to the application's config file.  See [.Net app.config in library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742929/net-app-config-in-library-project)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i want to write conenction strings to only one config file.

Comment: Then you can use your own files (like myConf.xml) and store connection string there. But i fyou want to use App.config, then it has to be in yout end application

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a connection string in the end application.

Say you have a library.dll and application.exe

Classes in application.exe use library.dll. And classes in library.dll need connection string from App.config. Then you have to provide the connection string in App.config of your application.exe.