# How to get connection string from app.config in another class library project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how do I get the connection string from app.config in another "class library project"

in the same class library I can use this code :

```
 DAL.Properties.Settings.Default.BayrueConnectionString;
```

**but the issue is that I cannot get it from my web app.**

thanks
[image]

Comment: Class Libraries use the configuration file of the application that is using them, so the settings need to be in the application's configuration file, not the libraries.  Libraries don't use config files.

Comment: as you can see I am using app.config

Comment: possible duplicate of [.Net app.config in library project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742929/net-app-config-in-library-project)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is no more elegant way than this. Add a static helper method to your class library which returns it.

```
public sealed class Helper
{
    private Helper()
    {
    }

    public static string GetBayrueConnectionString()
    {
        return DAL.Properties.Settings.Default.BayrueConnectionString;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thinks  this one will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Add reference to `System.Configuration`.

Use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DAL.Properties.Settings.BayrueConnectionString"]`

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

this the error I am getting when use your code

Comment: Are you sure that the app.config file is located in the folder where you run your app?

Comment: the app.config is in another project

Comment: When you deploy your app all the files need to be in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a new ConnectionStrings.config file in the project you'd like to reference.

ConnectionStrings.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data                        Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication-20130625013234;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication-20130625013234.mdf" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Next, unload your DAL project. Once unloaded, right click > Edit DAL.csproj.

Add the following element to the .csproj with the Include="{the ConnectionStrings.config you'd like to reference}":

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\ConnectionStrings.config" />
</ItemGroup>
```

[image: Solution Explorer]

Reload your project. This should add a ConnectionStrings.config file, shown above, to your project. Notice that both will open the same file. Now edit the app.config to reference the newly created .config file that was just added to your DAL:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config" />
```