# How to connect to database after hosting my .net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, hosting

I have a visual studio solution with 3 projects: DAL, BL & WebApplication1. As you probably assume, the latter is the interface.

I have a connectionString setting defined in the DAL project.

I have published my solution to my web hosting. Everything works fine, but it seems like my website doesn't connect to the database.

I can run WebService commands and get results using the BL, and every result I get that uses the DAL projects is like the DAL cannot connect to the database.

I have already updated the connectionString value to the value given to my by "myLittlePanel".

How can I achieve a connection to the database, or at least have a deeper understanding of the problem I'm facing?

(C#.net, visual studio 2012, Plesk panel & myLittleAdmin for SQL Server)

Comment: Well you could always add logging around the opening of the connection and catch any exceptions?

Comment: It is not exactly clear how that `connectionString` is defined in the DAL project or what the issue(exception) is, but it may be this problem -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742929/net-app-config-in-library-project

Comment: The exception is: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'myUser'"; I believe there's a problem with my connection string - how can I get the right one?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I understood what my problem was. I didn't have a 'password' attribute in the connectionString... Now I added it and everything works. :)

Comment: 1 upvote for not waiting until someone gave you the answer.