# How to Create a Connection File

Tags: c#

I am connecting to the database with the code below

```
     string connString = @"Data source = test2 ; Database=test1data ; User Id=a ; Password=test1234";
   using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                string sqlQuery = @"SELECT * from Zone";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(table);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource(table, null);
            }
```

But I wanted to create a file to connect  that could be changed.

### For example:

I'm connecting to a database, but changing this file I'll connect to another database

Comment: You should look at app.config

Comment: Show what you have done

Comment: show what you did..

Comment: what do you mean by ***"that could be changed."***? You mean on the fly?

Comment: I edited the post and added the code

Comment: There're like thousand solutions. We cannot know which one you want.
1) storing connection string in a file with one line; 2) storing connection string if app.config; 3) storing connection string in xml file and so on.

Comment: @KamikyIT I want the first option

Comment: @KamikyIT But I don´t know how I can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `<connectionStrings>` section to your `App.config`/`Web.config` file.

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="{your connection name}" connectionString="{your connection string}" />
  </connectionStrings>
...
</configuration>
```

Read it using the `ConfigurationManager`

```
using System.Configuration;

var connectionString = 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["{your connection name}"].ConnectionString;
```

See [ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That app.config is other file ?

Comment: `App.config` is the standard file to hold config values in .NET, it will be created automatically if you create a new project in Visual Studio.

Comment: I am using this on app.config `<add name="testdb" connectionstring="Data source = test ; Database=test1data ; User Id=a ; Password=2008"/>` and it give me a error when I run the error is ConfigurationErrorsException: Connectionstrings Unknown configuration section.

Comment: Did you put the `<add ... />` inside `<connectionStrings>`?

Comment: yes I did , my code is this `<connectionstrings>
  <add name="testdb" connectionstring="Data source = test ; Database=test1data ; User Id=a ; Password=2008" />
</connectionstrings>`

Comment: `<connectionStrings>` is case sensitve (uppercase "S"); also make sure that you only have one `<connectionStrings>` section in the file.

Comment: If your project is a library (instead of a console app), see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742929/net-app-config-in-library-project

Comment: my project is a form

Comment: Then see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114527/simplest-way-to-have-a-configuration-file-in-a-windows-forms-c-sharp-application