# ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration - Specifying the file to open

Tags: c#, configuration

I have an n-tier application. The service (backend) piece needs to have a configuration file and the client piece needs to have its own configuration file. Normally the client communicates to the service via WCF. However, for some testing, I'll reference the service assemblies in my client and bypass WCF. Makes some testing easier this way.

My question is this. When I run my client this way, the app.config that is used, in my service assemblies, is the client's config file and not its own config file. Is there a way I can tell ConfigurationManager to use my service assembly config file instead of the client config file, when I'm working this way?

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471042/wrong-app-config-being-loaded

Answer (score 0):

When you run in test visual studio does some magic and loads the servers configuration.  Once you add the references and run the client it does the normal behavior of loading the exe configuration in this case the clients.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you need better code isolation if you are trying to test things by getting around WCF. Your best bet is to build a service library that has no WCF dependencies and test that. Once you're satisfied with your testing of the service library, expose the service library using a WCF wrapper. You must have code inside the WCF operation contracts. I try to keep them separate for testability as it seems is your goal also.

A better way is to just add a test project with a project reference to your service library and a separate configuration file.